# Does App Engine strip EXIF data when using the Images.get_serving_url method?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using App Engine to serve images based on blob keys from BlobStore. For example, this is how I get the URL for a stored image in Python:

class Photo(db.Model):
    blob_key        = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

url = images.get_serving_url(self.blob_key)

My question is this: Does App Engine strip EXIF data from the images in the returned URL?

Comment: I don't think it 'strips' it, but since it transforms the image, it may not preserve it. It's probably easiest to just check if that's the case. :)